# Why a plot with the option "AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]" fail to display in GraphicsGrid?

Tags: plotting

I plot two picture one with the option "AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}" like this:

```
fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]]
fig2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

When I put these two pictures together:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{fig1, fig2}},Frame -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

the output is:
[image]
Why the plot with the option "AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]" fail to display?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why, but using Grid instead of GraphicsGrid fixes the problem (at least in V.11.2).

```
fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], ImageSize -> Medium];
fig2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> Medium];
Grid[{{fig1, fig2}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]